# How is HMAC hashed message decrypted on the receiver side

Tags: hash, mac, hmac

We know that MAC algorithm and key are used in both sender and receiver side to get the matching MAC tages to prove that the data is authentic.

Now in HMAC we know that, it makes use of crytographic hash function which is irreversible, so when we use HMAC from the sender side to encypt a message using the HMAC formula, then at the sender side how will the receiver decrypt the message (hash function is irreversible), so how is the message at the receiver end, integrity is preserved and validated? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the HMAC value is not decrypted at all. The recipient takes all the needed input and she computes the HMAC on her own side and check if the result she got it is equal to the value on the message she got.

You can roughly see the HMAC algorithm as an symmetric key signature. You cannot decrypt an HMAC, you only check that the value is correct.

Comment: YOu said that the receipient takes all the necessary input. What does that mean?The message sent by the sender is not know to the receiver,the sender sends the data using HMAC. Now the receiver needs to have the message to check the value whether its correct or not,from where will the receiver get the message to check the value??? In mac we have mac tag appended into the message, the message is separated from the senders tag and put into the MAC algortihm  along with the shared secret key to compute the MAC tag at receiver end.Explain to me on HMAC side ,how does it happen??

Comment: In the Encrypt-then-(H)MAC context the HMAC is computed on the ciphertext, so the recipient take the ciphertext she got, the hmac key (that is already know or derived from a know and preshared key) and compute the HMAC on her side, finally she check her result with the one sent with the ciphertext.
if the HMAC is computed on the plaintext, she has to decrypt the ciphertext and compute the HMAC on the plaintext, if values are equal the decryption is accepted, rejected otherwise.

Comment: Actually it is the same process of checking an hash value. How do you check if your download is not corrupted? You compute the hash value of the file and check the computed value against the one written on the website.

Comment: exactly, like the MD5checksum which we can use.correct???

Comment: Yes, but for the hmac you must give the authentication key as input as well.

Comment: The key is a preshared secret key, am I right?

Comment: It should depend on the standard, I'd use a preshared key to derive an encryption/decryption key and an authentication key. You use the first one with, let's say, AES, and the second one with, let's say, HMAC-SHA1.

Comment: OK. The authentication key which you are stating is sent by the sender separately or it get appended inside when we apply hashing to the message. Like suppose we use encrypt then HMAC, so the message is now passed to the receiver, the receiver will use the hash function  and the key to compute a value which should match with the hash value. So which in here will be the authentication  key??